# Perl print specific value from decoded json

Tags: perl

I'm trying to decode a json then only print specific values from it. I want to get the front and back from the json and save the file. Code is not getting past the decode_base64 and says "Not a HASH reference"

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper
use MIME:Base64

my $imageDir = "/usr/documents/images/";

my $testJson = '[{ "front":"", "back":"", "shortID":"", "longID":"" } ]';

my $Json = decode_json($testJson);

print Dumper $Json;

my $fImage = decode_base64($Json->{front});
my $fImagefile = saveFile('Front.jpg',$fImage);
my $bImage = decode_base64($Json->{back});
my $bImagefile = saveFile('Back.jpg',$bImage);

return ($fImagefile, $bImagefile);

sub saveFile{
    my ($file $image) = @_;

    my imageFile = $imageDir.$file;

   open (IMGFILE, '>'.$imageFile) or die;
   print IMGFILE $image;
   close IMGFILE;

   return $imageFile;
}
```

Comment: `$Json` is a reference to an array because the JSON document consists of an array.

Comment: Perhaps you intended `$Json->[0]{front}` and `$Json->[0]{back}` in your code based on `$testJson` variable;

Comment: @PolarBear what actually do the [0] mean. When I put that in it didn’t print anything

Comment: It does mean take very first element of an array (in your code `[` and `]` indicates that you will have an array reference.

Answer (score 2):

@ikegami already said this in a comment but I'll expand on it.

You have a JSON fragment that's an array, and the element in the array is a hash. T. You have one more level to drill down into to get what you want. The [perldsc (Perl Data Structures Cookbook)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) has lots of hints and tricks for multi-level data structures:

```
my $testJson = '[{ "front":"", "back":"", "shortID":"", "longID":"" } ]';

my $Json = decode_json($testJson);
print Dumper $Json;
```

In your Dumper output you should see something like this. It's an anonymous array with a hashref as its first and only element:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'longID' => '',
            'shortID' => '',
            'front' => '',
            'back' => ''
          }
        ];
```

If you want to process only that element, you can get the first element of the array reference. This is going to be the hash reference that you want to process:

```
my $element = $Json->[0];
my $fImage = decode_base64($element->{front});
...
```

But, you might want to process all the elements. Simply wrap a `foreach` around it:

```
foreach my $element ( @$Json ) {
    my $fImage = decode_base64($element->{front});
    ...
    }
```

Even though that array dereference is simple, the [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) introduced in v5.26 is quite nice and what I use most often:

```
foreach my $element ( $Json->@* ) {
    my $fImage = decode_base64($element->{front});
    ...
    }
```